# I want to travel USA on B2 for vacation but I have f1 visa

Tags: air-travel

I want to visit USA on tourist visa but I have a f1 visa which was stamped in dec 2015.Due to some problems I didn't travel for masters.Is it still valid,Can I go on other visa even having F1 visa..!!Should I go for B2 visa interview.How can I proceed to get Tourist visa...

Please help me out..!!!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are not a citizen of a [Visa Waiver Program country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program#Eligible_countries) (and are otherwise eligible for the VWP), you need to apply for a B-2 visa at a US Consulate. The F-1 visa is only valid for study, and you will only be admitted to the country with an F-1 visa if an approved educational institution has indicated that you are a student in good standing in the [SEVIS database](https://www.ice.gov/sevis).

There is no reason you can't apply for a B-2 visa while you have a F-1 visa in your passport, though you may be asked to explain why you didn't use your visa. As with any non-immigrant visa, you'll need to show strong ties to your home country and an intent to return home at the end of your trip.